# React how to remove unnecessary terminal information?

Tags: reactjs, terminal

I am unsure what this is. But I would like to remove these last 5 lines with in the terminal as it's messy and doesn't contribute to helping me (As this used to not exists, But I've clearly done something to add this to my terminal). It's a bit of a pain as when I have react errors I need to scroll past these 5 lines.

ALSO: If theirs a proper name for this it would be cool if you could say. As cause calling it 5 lines isn't really the proper way :).

[Picture Explaining Messy Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9keqD.png)

Comment: Looks like https://webpack.js.org/configuration/stats/ have been changed (though I'm not 100% sure)

Comment: @TajLonghurstSoft Welcome to StackOverflow! Please consider adding a short description of the issue statement using code blocks instead of posting image references.

Answer (score 0):

downgrade react-scripts from 5.0.0 to 4.0.3

```
npm i react-scripts@4.0.3
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).